# Does PreparedStatement.setFetchDirection() make a difference for an Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

Does `PreparedStatement.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD)` make a difference for an Oracle DB?

I'm on project to upgrade the database and application server for the power facilities and line maintenance system of a large electrical utility company. We are testing the new set up now (Oracle 12c and JBoss 7).

Sometimes the queries to the db are taking minutes to get an answer. I've suggested doing `PreparedStatement.setFetchSize(int rows)`, where rows being the number of rows of information the user wants to see on his screen. Many posters here in Stackoverflow and elsewhere have said `setFetchSize()` is important to getting the network connection optimized.

But I noticed the `PreparedStatement` also has `setFetchDirection()`. There's `FETCH_FORWARD`, `FETCH_REVERSE` and `FETCH_UNKNOWN`. I've seen this mentioned many times, but I've not seen anyone saying how much of a benefit it is.

If it helps to understand the situation - the power company services 30 million customers, with decades of records (from nuclear power plants down to utility poles). The users of the service will be maintenance crews, office staff, both from with the company and from subcontractors. So, the computer skills and patience of the users may not tolerate a 3 minute wait to find the locations of the transformers they need to repair.

Comment: _"a 3 minute wait to find the locations of the transformers"_, this sound like you should do the search in the database, not after retrieving the data.

Comment: The default already is `ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD`, so explicitly setting it will not have any impact. This is one of the more obscure features of JDBC, I don't know if this is supported by Oracle, but if it does, I don't think using another fetch direction than the default will have a positive result on the performance.

Comment: Assuming the amount of data that gets actually selected and displayed is rather small, there is little use in trying to optimize the cursor handling. You either need to work on the select statement itself or create useful indexes. Sometimes, telling Oracle to analyze its tables helps a lot, too.

Comment: What I do not understand is, if ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD is the default for Oracle and Oracle does not support ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE and ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN, why have setFetchDirection()?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says

> "The JDBC 2.0 standard allows the ability to pre-specify the
>   direction, known as the fetch direction, for use in processing a
>   result set. This allows the JDBC driver to optimize its processing."

However Oracle also says "the Oracle JDBC drivers support only the forward preset value" ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD

> "The values ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE and ResultSet.FETCH_UNKNOWN are
>   not supported."

So, my guess is that if you are using JDBC 2.0 standard drivers, then you can optimize fetch by saying setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_REVERSE) when wanting to find overdue maintenance work. But if you are using Oracle JDBC drivers you are out of luck.

(Downvote me if I'm wrong - I know that improves your geek creed.)